# How do I create a hardlink in WiX

Tags: wix, hardlink

Is it possible to create a hardlink in WiX without creating a Custom Action? I found [this 
thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=wix-users&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=200708) describing the problem, but it doesn't provide an answer. The reason for wanting to create a hardlink is that I've got four different applications sharing the same prerequisites, and these take up all available space on the server. It would be nice to share them somehow.

I'm using WiX 3.0

Comment: The thread you mentioned does provide an answer: "MSI doesn't have support so you'd have to ( carefully ) roll your own CA pattern to do this.".

Comment: @nabulke This should be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The thread you mentioned does provide an answer: "*MSI doesn't have support so you'd have to ( carefully ) roll your own CA pattern to do this.*".

Moved from comments